# Is it possible preview my dog adult size?

Tags: dogs, weight, crossbreed

Few days ago, I adopted a three-month dog. I don't know his breed. Actually, he's mixed-breed. He weighs less than 1Kg now.

Would someone guess his possible size and weight in the future based on his current size, weigth and age?

Here are some picture:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to guess, how we usually estimate their adult size is by looking at both parents. Another way is from paws, large paws tend to mean big dogs (though there are some exceptions I.e cocker spaniels).

From pictures, age and weight he's going to stay small.